# Configure Android to allow third-part application to handle SMS (text) messages?

Tags: sms

I have a Huawei P8 Lite running stock software (Android 5.0 and EMUI 3.1), and use a third-party application (MyPhoneExplorer, a.k.a. MPE) to handle SMS messages from my Windows computer.

Although I never had that issue with an older Android phone running Cyanogenmod, the new phone often prompts me with the following dialog to allow MPE to handle text messages:
[image]

Is there a way to tell Android to allow that application once and for all, and stop bothering me?

Thank you.

Comment: That looks like a problem with the ROM.  Is MPE installed to the phone storage or to the internal/external SD card?

Comment: In the phone storage.